# Does Qt Qml Have QMdiArea?

Tags: qt, qml, qmdiarea

Does Qml have QMdiArea and QMdiSubWindow? If so can you show me a little example? I have a cool idea for a program design that I would like to create.

Answer (score 2):

QML does not have something like QMdiArea. But you can place your qml file in a QMdiArea widget. It's enought to set a QDeclarativeView as viewport widget of the QMdiArea or by putting the QDeclarativeView inside QMdiArea(It's just a QWidget subclass 
like any other).

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured i'd have to. Thanks tho